# Inside a innermost tag. How to get all the formating operations effective on the text?

Tags: html, css-selectors, html-agility-pack

My requirement is to get the news content from different news websites..approximately...250. so news content is somewhere in the body, i can go to the first paragraph of where ever the news content is based on the google snippets/metainfo. but to get the other paragraphs of the news content i am trying to go up the HTML tree till i find a division or a table body...but because of that i am getting some undesired text i.e is not related to the news item. so what i found out is...all the relevant news items in most of the webpages are styled or formatted in a similar way. So is there a way i can capture all the styling happening in the first paragraph and then i can filter out unwanted text using that formating information.

I am using HTML agility pack and xpath for my requirement. Thank you.

Comment: i mean the fonsize, fonttype, etc formatting on the selected node text.

Comment: Is the "formating information" in the input source (as in `@style` per element)? If the answer is not, this is not an XPath question.

Comment: Found an alternate way to this problem, its 99% accurate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could like at my answer of the following question on SO: [Advanced HTML Agility Pack usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607782/advanced-html-agility-pack-useage), it seems to be somewhat related to yours.